# Rename file with unknown extension

Tags: php

I have a file with two possible names: `slide_f.png` or `slide_f.jpg`.

I want to `rename` this file to `slide'.$nr.'.jpg` or `slide'.$nr.'.png` depending on the previous extension.

How can I do it without knowing the initial file extension?

Comment: If you will rename, the file must exist first, right? If it exists, can you get it extension? Your question is a little vague...

Comment: Yes the file exists, but could be either `slide_f.png` or `slide_f.jpg`.

Comment: Hint: [`glob`](http://PHP.net/glob)

Comment: Follow @Luigi Siri's tip, check if one of them exists, then you get the extension of that existing one.

Comment: So how is the existing file name determined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). Then, proceed to rename.

```
if(file_exists($name.'.jpg'))
{
    rename($name.'.jpg', $new_name.'.jpg')
}
elseif(file_exists($name.'.png'))
{
    rename($name.'.png', $new_name.'.png')
}
else
{
    echo "the file doesn't exists";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `glob()` to wildcard match the file by its prefix, then pathinfo to decompose the filename into its constituent parts. Then rebuild and rename

```
$files = glob('slide_f.*');
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
   rename($file, "{$basename}{$nr}.{$ext}");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line `$basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);` be `$basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
if(file_exists("slide_f.png")){
    //rename to png
}else if(file_exists("slide_f.jpg")){
    //rename to jpg
}else{
    // unknown file format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [glob](http://de.php.net/glob), then you get the filename.

```
$fnList = glob('slide_f.*');
foreach($fnList as $fn){
    $fn = preg_replace('/_f\.',$nr,  $fn);
}
```